# How to trigger Django signals only once on multiple receivers

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I am looking for a way to do the following (keep in mind, if this is not possible with signals, I'm happy if you know any alternatives)

But let's say we have a signal defined as follows:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Model1)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model2)
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model3)
def my_signal_handle(sender , **kwargs)
    # some code here
```

Now, all 3 models (Model1, Model2, Model3) are related. So when creating a new resource, one can provide all informations, which results in all 3 tables being saved with a new row. I would love to only trigger `my_signal_handle` once in that case. So basically per transaction.

Also, when updating for example, one could only update, let's say Model3, and in that case I still want this signal to run.

So goal is -> No matter how many models are affected, I want to run this signal once.

Hope it makes sense, happy to clarify better if needed. I was looking at adding a signal per transaction or something, but couldn't find exactly what I need.

Comment: You can write 3 signals, on each you create caching logic, check/write to cache if any signal received, and run the main logic only when all three are written in cache.

Comment: Hmm.. how does that solve the second case? When updating, what happens when only Model3 get's updated (patched). We would then only write into cache for that one signal, others wouldn't run :/

Comment: For the second case, you can add flags in the caching logic that indicates that one model save can initiate the handler. Or it might be better to create a mediator class that handles the post_save behaviour of these 3 classes. But this will limit the way to save these models through that class only